# Is it possible to force working copy version to 1.7 or 1.8 when performing a checkout with SVNKit?

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I've got a tool that uses [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) to do some automated tasks. This tool must coexist with other ones in different environments. Because of this, in some ones I've to checkout repositories so that the working copy is in version 1.7 and others in 1.8. (Unfortunately I cannot upgrade to use 1.8 clients everywhere)

The checkout is done as follows:

```
SVNClientManager svnClientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance();
SVNUpdateClient updateClient = svnClientManager.getUpdateClient();
updateClient.doCheckout(
        SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(uri), dstDir, 
        SVNRevision.HEAD, SVNRevision.HEAD, SVNDepth.INFINITY, true);
```

Obviously, depending on the version of SVNKit (1.7 or 1.8) used, the local working copy has the same format.

For now, the solution is to have two versions of the tool where the only difference is the version of the SVNKit lib. But I would like to have a single version, which can be configured to use svn 1.7 or 1.8 format.

Is it possible to force the desired working copy format using SVNKit 1.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's not possible. Each version of SVNKit only does the checkout in the current version (like the svn tool does).

The workaround has been to ship both versions and configure which to use in the classpath when the tool is launched.